# Set domain on listening IP ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, networking, ip, hosts

So I have working application on ubuntu 16.10 server which listen to :3030 port. Now its reachable and working when I visit it via http: `http://*.*.*.*:3030` and I want to make it working on my domain - `domain.com -> *.*.*.*:3030` - how to make it? DNS already changed and pointing to the server via cloudflare. Also I want to make it reachable via www alias

This is my /etc/hosts contents:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

Comment: Well, you need to set CNAME in cloudflare under dns section. How `/etc/hosts` file looks like?

Comment: @MilosM everything is set on cloudflare and about hosts I've edited the question

Comment: You do mean domain.com:3030 -> n.n.n.n:3030, don't you?

Comment: no I mean domain.com -> n.n.n.n.n:3030 @AlexP

Comment: That's not possible. DNS cannot provide a port number.

Comment: So how to redirect it? I see other services using the same method (running node application on their server) and pointing domain to *.*.*.*:port. Also I had once created sub.domain.com which was pointing to `*.*.*.*:port` too but can't remember how